# Migrate Web Service from Tomcat to Wildly

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to migrate a SOAP Web service that works well with Tomcat but gives following error with JBoss:

```
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:119)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:120)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:66)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:186)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No DestinationFactory was found for the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/https.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.getDestinationFactory(DestinationFactoryManagerImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:170)
    ... 16 more
```

I did try to remove       from standalone.xml after which the web service started working but after doing this my another web service that was made with jboss stopped so i have to retain this module in standalone.xml.

Comment: What 3rd party jars are you including in your app?

Comment: Hi all the jars that i am using is there in my other web sevice which i created  for jboss and its working fine , but in this webservice i use JAXB binding

Comment: Let's be more explicit then. Does your application contain any Apache CXF or Axis jars? Or any XML parsers or APIs such as `xml-apis`, `xerces`, etc. In general you often need to remove stuff from your application when you move it from Tomcat to a full Java EE implementation. And old JBoss versions had peculiar class loading too.

Comment: it contains axis-1.2.1 jar

Comment: Well get rid of that (it's extremely ancient). The full list of jars would still be helpful.

Comment: antlr-2.7.6.jar,asm-attrs.jar,asm.jar,axis-1.2.1.jar,cglib-2.1.3.jar,commons-codec-1.3.jar,commons-collections-2.1.1.jar,commons-csv-20070730.jar,commons-discovery-0.4.jar,commons-lang-2.0.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar,el-api.jar,hibernate-annotations.jar,hibernate,commons-annotations.jar,hibernate,entitymanager.jar,hibernate-tools.jar,hibernate3.jar,javassist.jar,javax.mail-1.5.1.jar,jdbc2_0-stdext.jar,jta.jar
jtidy-r8-20060801.jar
log4j-1.2.11.jar
ojdbc6.jar
swingx-all-1.6.4.jar
toplink-essentials.jar
webui-jsf.jar

Comment: Get rid of the axis jar, as well as ejb3-persistence.jar,el-api.jar,javax.mail-‌​1.5.1.jar,jdbc2_0-st‌​dext.jar and jta.jar. These later classes are all provided by your JDK or WildFly. Are you building with Maven?

Comment: no i am not using maven.I removed jars it still gives error

Comment: What tool did you use to generate your web service skeleton?

Comment: Actually this is an old web service which was runnig with tomcat , i am trying to make it work with JBoss.

For making it work with jboss i tried commenting out webservice module extension from standalone.xml then it worked fine.But i can't do that because my other web service that i created stopped running.

Comment: If you have the WSDL then I would regenerate the skeleton service and JAXB artifacts. You can use either the JDK `wsimport` command or the WildFly `wsconsume` command to do this.

Comment: I removed these errors by regenerating the webservice by wsdl and JAXB artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed these errors by regenerating the webservice by wsdl and JAXB artifacts.